# Input value didnt display

Tags: html, forms, thymeleaf, bootstrap-modal

**The code snippet below is form that embeded in the bootstrap modal to allow the user create a new subject for current system. In the form, I have included one text input to accept the data. In that text input, I have assign `value = "incomplete"` as the default value. However, the default value didnt show as expected when the webpage is running.**

```
<div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="adminAddExamForm" method="POST"
                            th:action="@{/process_AdminAddExam}" th:object="${exam}">
                            <div class="mb-2">
                                <label for="status" class="col-form-label">Status</label>
                                <input type="text" value="incomplete" class="form-control" id="status" th:field="*{status}" autocomplete="off" disabled>
                            </div>
                       </form>
</div>
```

The below code snippet and screenshot is taken from chrome dev tools. Even though I have assign the value, but it still show nothing

```
<div class="mb-2">
                                <label for="status" class="col-form-label">Status</label>
                                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                            </div>
```

[image: Chrome Dev tools Screenshot]

Comment: `th:field` overwrites the `name`, `id`, and `value` of a tag.  If you want the status to default to `Incomplete` you should set it on your object in the controller and then `th:field` will take care of the rest.

Comment: Noted with thanks

Answer (score 1):

No `value = "incomplete"` found in your codes. only `value = ""`

Replace

```
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
```

with

```
<input type="text" value="incomplete" class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
```

**Update**:
If still doesn't show, check the css. Is there a property that makes the text transparent to its background.

Comment: I now add already, it still show nothing

Comment: like I mentioned in the post above, although I add the default value, but when I inspect on the chrome dev tool there, the value attribute show the empty value

Comment: Second, I follow ur suggestion to check the css property, I didn't found any property that will cause the text transparent

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I use the javascript to assign it the default value.

```
document.getElementById("status").defaultValue = "Incomplete";
```